# Is it possible in android to register for the intent of a long click on a link?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to give users the ability to long quick on a link in the google chrome app for android and give them the option to send that link to my app for a download. I've been looking at the list of intents in android and don't see it anywhere. I also want to give them the option to copy a link and allow them to transfer this directly into my app. Is this possible in android. Or should I just have them select the text and then as soon as the app is opened copy it directly into the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the share function of Android, this is for similar solutions, you can simply put your app to the share list. It's advantage, that it will not only work with the Google Chrome app, but also with almost any browser.

You can do this with adding an intent filter to your activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

More about this on Android developer: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html